# Create react projects through custom CLI

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, customization

I am new to `React` and worked on `Angular` & `Ionic`.
Now I want to create project/utility which will behave similarly to the following:
[Ionic CLI](https://ionicframework.com/getting-started#cli)

If you notice in the above link, here we can create the different types of projects with using CMD. i.e, *Blank, Tabs, SideMenu, etc.*

I want to replicate similar things using `React`. Also keep in mind the folder structure for the project including **Reducer, Action, Constant, etc**.

Given an example, Every project has few things in common like Login Page, Header, Footer, Sidebar, etc. So depending on the requirement another team will be able to create the project they required.

Any help will be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
npx create-react-app appName
```

this will allow you to create the new react app

https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-component-folder

use this to install it

```
npm i -S create-react-component-folder
```

this dependency will allow you to create component app by using

```
npx crcf componentName
```

this will serve your react app in browser

```
npx start
```

Comment: No this question is not about genenrating components/any other parts. I want to create custom projects/application that can be used by other team member with unique folder structure and core parts. I understand the answer pasted by you will help me to create components but that is not what I required.